# mongodb query with $in record with subsequent condition

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

My dataset is like the below, where _v is the version of the document (after changes).

1. record id:1, _v: 1
2. record id:2, _v: 2
3. record id:3, _v: 3

Is there a way to query this by passing in the id (i am using $in now) AND check if the corresponding _v is not matching? For example if my input is {id: 3, version:1}. I need it retrieved because the database has the latest version as 3 (_v:3)

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can negate your version check with [$ne](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/ne/).

```js
db.collection.find({ 
  id: {$in: [3]},
  _v: {$ne: 1}
})
```